# Align text vertically in 2 columns of a table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with 2 columns and on each column I have a different size of font (the bigger size font also strong).
My problem is the vertical alignment of the text: it doesn't align vertically (see the image):
[image]

Here's my html code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .big-text-size {
      font-size: 3.5em;
    }
    .small-text-size {
      font-size: 1.1em;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
      <table>
        <td class="big-text-size">
          <strong>My doctor's name</strong>
        </td>
        <td class="small-text-size"> Daniel Boro </td>
      </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions why does it happen?

Comment: Please make your example more minimal: Only keep those things in that are necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Tables should be used for tabular data only - not layout

Comment: @petermeissner: got it, remove unnecessary code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tweak the vertical alignment of your different-size-text ([see here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp)):

```
<html>
<head><style>
  .big-text-size {
      font-size: 3.5em;
      vertical-align: text-bottom;
    }
  .small-text-size {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
  }
</style></head>
<body>
      <table>
        <td class="big-text-size">
          <strong>My doctor's name</strong>
        </td>
        <td class="small-text-size"> Daniel Boro </td>
      </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second table doesn't have any rows...

```
<table>
    <tr> <!-- Missing -->
        <td class="small-text-size">Daniel Boro</td>
        <td class="big-text-size"><strong>My doctor's name</strong></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I inserted <tr></tr> tag as you said but it didn't change: still looks the same

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

try including rows in your table..

you can also visit this site http://daker.me/2014/04/4-css-tricks-for-vertical-alignment.html It provides 4 CSS tricks that you can use to align text vertically in a table cell